# Error reading contents of build/intermediates/data-binding-compiler/debug/dependent-lib-artifacts directory

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding

> Error:Execution failed for task ':syh_library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug'.
>   failure, see logs for details.
>     Error reading contents of /Users/Rock/workspace/android_workspase/syh-android/Syh/syh_library/build/intermediates/data-binding-compiler/debug/dependent-lib-artifacts directory java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/Rock/workspace/android_workspase/syh-android/Syh/syh_library/build/intermediates/data-binding-compiler/debug/dependent-lib-artifacts

Comment: This looks like something in your build process is broken. Have you tried a clean and re-build? Proguard and other libraries that use annotations can also impact data binding.

Comment: Could you edit to provide more details?  Perhaps some code you are using might shed some light on this issue and an explanation so we know what you are doing and how.

Answer (score 22):

Deleting the .gradle folder of the root project and re-sync gradle worked for me. Unaware of the root cause though.

Comment: This is the only solution that woks for me. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you so much, couldn't sleep last night because of this. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I recreated the folder structure mentioned in exception and the error was gone. Seems to be the only way. ***Clean***, ***Rebuild*** and ***Clear caches*** didn't work.

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did; it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked, but following a `clean` the issue came right back

Answer (score 2):

Delete .gradle folder and sync project.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, but I don't think the way can be copy.

I have a lib that used **data-binding**. I removed it when this error appeared.

Then make all operations of **data-binding** in application module.

I tried to use [minimlistic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768685/minimlistic)'s answer, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the files from another project to given folder, built again, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I have resolved it by adding the following line in my module which was not using data binding.

```
dataBinding.enabled = false
```